# Creating a PDF merge tool with itextsharp that supports embedded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, merge, itext

I want to create a PDF merge tool using itextsharp that will preserve embedded JavaScript from the input files.
I haven't used itextsharp before so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Before I spend time creating this, I just want to check if this is feasible? When I copy one page from the input file to the new document, will this also copy the JavaScript or do I need to explicitly get the JavaScript from one file and copy it into the new document?

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: How generic do you want your tool to be? Be aware! Methods from the individual PDFs may have the same name. JS code may assume a certain document structure, e.g. it may assume certain stuff to be located on a fixed page X which in the course of the merger has moved, or it may assume form fields to have only one widget which may have changed in the course of the merge... I assume you plan this JS-aware merge tool because you need something like that for yourself; analyzing the JS in the PDFs you want to join may help you evaluate your plan.

Comment: I guess I need to to be fairly generic, I think we can assume the method names will be different. I've had a look at some of the JS in the pdf, and it all appears to be at document and it appears to be at document level based around buttons. I'm not all that familiar with JS within pdf and have just been given some files to merge.

Comment: The buttons have different names in the different documents?